# Can I share one channel by 10K or 20K, 100K visitors?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building my JAVA app base on GAE, it using the Channel API, I have a question:  can I let all visitors share one channel to receive the messages from my APP ? It's likes boardcast, any extra cost for this solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have your read the docs?  Channel API is not for broadcast.

Comment: but here Jonathan Newmuis said it's works as this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271274/google-app-engine-channel-api#comment21647279_8272098

Comment: It's misleading.  Channel API implementation on the dev server and production server were completely different, especially back 2 years ago.  The dev server implementation used polling, and an update on a channel could be seen on multiple clients.  But it's not intended to work that way and the production server doesn't work that way.